# Deleting ID from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I am trying to delete the users username from the database when s/he logs out. My code is the following which doesn't work. I Think it may have something to do with the connection string (database, password thing)

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Query As String
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=*Mypassword*;Database=myusers")
    con.Open()
    Query = "Delete FROM users WHERE name  =" + loginuser.Text
    'Table = users
    'Name = Varchar(20)
    'loginuser.text = Name (username)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)
    MsgBox(Query)
    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (i > 0) Then
        MsgBox("Record is Successfully Deleted")
    Else
        MsgBox("Record is not Deleted")
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: What would happen if I entered `'';DROP TABLE users;` into the login box? You're practically begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String literals need to be enclosed in single quotes so your query should be:

```
Query = "Delete FROM users WHERE name  = '" + loginuser.Text + "'"
```

Also concatenating a string into a SQL statement opens you up to SQL injection attacks (or even just think about someone putting "O'Brien" as the login name).  You should always use parameters instead.

Comment: This technique is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

You are not enclosing name value with quotes in your sql string, 
Ex: `Delete FROM users WHERE name = 'abcname'`

Change your code to use parameters which is clean and secure way to pass values and you don't have to worry about quotes when working with string parameters

```
Query = "Delete FROM users WHERE name  = @name"
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)
MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",loginuser.Text)
```